# Apache redirect loop

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2

Can anyone explain why I keep getting a re-direct loop? I'm attempting to make https the default port.
I am running Apache on an ec-2 instance:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
        ServerName myserver.com
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^/$ https://myserver.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/clients"
        ServerName clients.myserver.com

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    ServerName www.myserver.com
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/myserver.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/private-key-decrypted.key

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

try a "redirect" instead of "rewrite" Here is my config as reference. Not entirely sure on the "why" you'd be having the problem though, tbh. Can only say that this configuration seems to work.

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin root@localhost
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerName <server>.<domain>.<extension>
ServerAlias <server>
Redirect permanent / https://<server>.<domain>.<extension>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin root@localhost
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerName <server>.<domain>.<extension>
ServerAlias <server>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/certs/<server>.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/certs/<server>.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though using `mod_rewrite` is possible it is not recommended as it may cause redirect loops as in your example. Using `Redirect` is a better approach. Your configuration could look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName yourserver.com
   Redirect permanent / https://yourserver.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName yourserver.com
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
   SSLEngine On
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

This also means that will need to have two `VirtualHost` sections per host. Here is a link to the documentation https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL.